# Gostaria de filtrar um select a partir do clique de um botão

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Eu preciso que ao clicar no botão Filtro1, por exemplo, apareça no select apenas as option "test1A" e "test2A", pode ser usando JQuery, Javascript ou Bootstrap. Agradeço desde já

```html
<button>Filtro1</button>
<button>Filtro2</button>
<button>Filtro3</button>

<select>
  <option>test1A</option>
  <option>test1B</option>https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask#
  <option>test2A</option>
  <option>test2B</option>
  <option>test3A</option>
  <option>test3B</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em português! Já tentou fazer algo? Poderia colocar seu código?

Comment: [Achar que nós faremos o seu trabalho todo de graça](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5486#5486)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Vamos lá, Rhuã.

Primeiramente, eu não sei como está sendo populado seu `select`, portanto, irei assumir que está sendo populado diretamente no HTML, sendo assim, com javascript precisaremos primeiro percorrer suas options, salvando-as para que possamos posteriormente "repopular" seu select com elas, quando o filtro for desativado.

Como nos deu poucos detalhes, certamente minha resposta não será a melhor solução para o seu problema programaticamente falando, mas espero que possa te dar um norte para onde seguir.

Para que possamos identificar seus elementos, definiremos aqui um id quando necessário.

```js
// definimos os valores correspondentes a cada filtro;
const filtersValues = {
  1: [1, 3],
  2: [2, 4],
  3: [5, 6]
};

const select = document.getElementById('select-teste');
const filterButton = document.getElementsByClassName('filter');
const removeFiltersButton = document.getElementById('remove-filters');

let optionsFiltered = Array(); //definimos uma variavel vazia como array para salvar as options que deverão aparecer após filtrar.

//guardamos as options originais para repopular o select quando necessário.
const originalOptions = Array();
for (let i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++) {
  originalOptions.push(select.options[i]);
}

for (let i = 0; i < filterButton.length; i++) {
  //escutaremos o evento clique do botão filter1 e executaremos nossa função de filtro.
  filterButton[i].addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    dataFilter = event.target.dataset.filter;
    // percorreremos o array correspondente ao elemento clicado dentro do objeto filterValues.
    for (let i = 0; i < filtersValues[dataFilter].length; i++) {
      // logo em seguida, percorremos as options originais verificando se o valor do filtro é igual ao atual.
      for (let j = 0; j < originalOptions.length; j++) {
        // quando o valor é igual, guardamos no nosso array optionsFiltered.
        if (filtersValues[dataFilter][i] == originalOptions[j].value) {
          optionsFiltered.push(originalOptions[j]);
        }
      }
    }

    // apagamos todas as options
    select.innerHTML = '';

    // faremos append das options filtradas.
    for (let i = 0; i < optionsFiltered.length; i++) {
      select.appendChild(optionsFiltered[i]);
    }

    // redefinimos o array optionsFiltered como um array vazio.
    optionsFiltered = Array();
  });
}

removeFiltersButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // apagamos todas as options
  select.innerHTML = '';
  // inserimos novamente as originais
  for (let i = 0; i < originalOptions.length; i++) {
    select.appendChild(originalOptions[i]);
  }
});
```

```html
<button class="filter" data-filter="1">Filtro 1</button>
<button class="filter" data-filter="2">Filtro 2</button>
<button class="filter" data-filter="3">Filtro 3</button>
<button id="remove-filters">Remover filtros</button>

<select id="select-teste">
  <!-- adicionei tambem values às options -->
  <option value="1">test1A</option>
  <option value="2">test1B</option>
  <option value="3">test2A</option>
  <option value="4">test2B</option>
  <option value="5">test3A</option>
  <option value="6">test3B</option>
</select>
```